# How do I create a paragraph in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, paragraph, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I am running through a tutorial and even though I have typed this code exactly as instructed it is coming back with a syntax error.
Can anyone explain how to create a paragraph in ruby?

My attempt is shown below.

Thanks

```
Puts <<PARAGRAPH
There's something going on here.
With the PARAGRAPH thing.
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
PARAGRAPH
```

Comment: Exactly as instructed? Check your case for "puts".

Comment: Shame on your instructor, then.

Comment: Next time, please provide a link to the tutorial in question: http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex9.html

Comment: @LarsHaugseth: The instructor used `puts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `Puts`. You want `puts`.

Answer (score 2):

puts it's a [method of module Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-putc), you should write it with small letter: `puts`

Comment: Ahh, fallen at the first hurdle. Thanks guys! I wont miss something like that again.

Answer (score 1):

The [original tutorial](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex9.html) had `puts`, not `Puts`:

```
# Here's some new strange stuff, remember type it exactly.

days = "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"
months = "Jan\nFeb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug"

puts "Here are the days: ", days
puts "Here are the months: ", months

puts <<PARAGRAPH
There's something going on here.
With the PARAGRAPH thing
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
PARAGRAPH
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Some Guy said, assigning `"Here are the days: ", days` to `puts` is your problem. When you hit the line `puts <<PARAGRAPH`, the interpreter attempts to append `PARAGRAPH` to the array `puts` instead of generating the here doc, but of course `PARAGRAPH` is undefined.

It's kind of interesting (though not super helpful) to note that you could actually still force it to work with the syntax

```
puts(<<PARAGRAPH)
Theres something going on here.
With the paragraph thing.
Well be able to type as much as we like.
Even four lines.
PARAGRAPH
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing here you can do here. You could do:

```
<<PARAGRAPH
typing lines of data, etc
more input
PARAGRAPH
```

or 'any' capitalized word you choose:

```
<<BUILDING
typing lines, etc
BUILDING
```

Every word I have used works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have blank space at the end of PARAGRAPH. Make sure there is no space after PARAGRAPH and you are good to go.

```
puts <<PARAGRAPH
There's something going on here.
With the PARAGRAPH thing.
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
PARAGRAPH
```